# Toggling JSON Elements through javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

My goal is to toggle the "prev" and "ext" elements i got from the JSON File in this way:

Here's [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e99ztmaf/17/)

*The menu bar looks like:*

[ "prev_Person1" "Person1" "ext_Person1" ... "Person2" ... "Person3" ... ]

I set prev_Person1 and ext_Person1 to be not visible at first. I am trying it with the jquery function at the end of the javascript code.

When i click on the "Go Back"-Button the object "prev_Person1" should be shown, in this case it is the name Jeanette.

When i click on the "Go Forward"-Button the object "ext_Person1" should be shown, in this case it is the name Angela.

The bar should now look like

**[Jeanette Angie Angela ... ]**

And i wanted to save the changes to the local storage, so that when i navigate to other pages it doesn't go back to its first state.

```
<div class="scrollmenu" id="myHeader">
    <a style="float:left" href="index.html">Menu</a>    
</div>
<button id="prev"> Go Back </button>
<button id="ext"> Go Forward </button>
```

**CSS:**

```
 body 
 {
   margin: 0;
   font-family: Arial;
 }
 .top-container 
 {
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 padding: 2px;
 text-align: center;
 }
 div.scrollmenu {
 background-color: #0000A0;
 overflow: auto;
 white-space: nowrap;
 }

div.scrollmenu a {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
background-color: #777;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
data = 
{
"persons": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Angie",
    "link": "*",
    "prev": [ { "id" : "6",
                "name" : "Jeanette"}],
    "ext": [ { "id" : "4",
               "name" : "Angela"}]    
},    
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Rana",
    "link": "Rana.html",
    "prev": [ { "id" : "7",
                 "name" :"Angelika"}],
    "ext": [ { "id" : "5",
                 "name" :"Mona"}]    
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Tamara",
    "link": "Tamara.html",
    "prev": [ { "id" : "4",
                 "name" : "Angela"}],
    "ext": [ { "id" : "8",
                 "name" :"Tala"}]             
}
]}

var id;
var name;
var link;
var prev;
var ext;

for (var key in data) {
for (var i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) {
    id_persons = data[key][i].id;
    name = data[key][i].name;
    ext = data[key][i].ext;
    prev = data[key][i].prev;
    link = data[key][i].link;

// just like add the add all the actors     
for (var j = 0; j < ext.length; j++) {
    var ext_person = ext[j].name;
    var id_ext = ext[j].id;

    }
for (var p = 0; p < prev.length; p++) {
    var prev_person = prev[p].name;
    var id_prev = prev[p].id;
}
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // menu_bar_knows is for the prev elements //
    var menu_bar_prev = document.createElement('a');
    menu_bar_prev.id = id_prev;

    menu_bar_prev.innerHTML =
    prev_person + '</a>';
    // End of menu_bar_knows elements // 
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // menu_bar is for the main path elements //
    var menu_bar = document.createElement('a');
    menu_bar.className = 'menu_bar';
    menu_bar.id = id_persons;
    menu_bar.href = link;

    menu_bar.innerHTML =
    name + '</a>';
    // End of menu_bar elements // 
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // menu_bar_knows is for the ext elements //
    var menu_bar_ext = document.createElement('a');
    menu_bar_ext.id = id_ext;

    menu_bar_ext.innerHTML =
    ext_person + '</a>';
    // End of menu_bar_knows elements // 
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Calling the elements in the header
    document.getElementById('myHeader').appendChild(menu_bar_prev);
    document.getElementById('myHeader').appendChild(menu_bar);
    document.getElementById('myHeader').appendChild(menu_bar_ext);
    // End 
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------   
 }
}
//-------------------------------------------//

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function(angie) {
        var isVisible;
        $("#4, #6").toggle(false);

        if (localStorage.getItem('prev_angie_visible') != null) {
            isVisible = localStorage.getItem('prev_angie_visible') === 
            'false' ? false : true;
        $("#6").toggle(isVisible);
        }

        if (localStorage.getItem('ext_angie_visible') != null) {
            isVisible = localStorage.getItem('ext_angie_visible') === 
            'false' ? false : true;
        $("#4").toggle(isVisible);
        }

    $("#prev_angie").click(function(){
        $("#6").toggle();
        localStorage.setItem('prev_angie_visible', $("#6").is(":visible"));
    });

    $("#ext_angie").click(function(){
        $("#4").toggle();
        localStorage.setItem('ext_angie_visible', $("#4").is(":visible"));
    });
  });
 })
```

I would be very thankful for every tip or solution!!

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Comment: After careful examination (approximately 45 minutes), I have determined that I cannot make heads nor tails of your code, or your question for that matter. I have no idea what your code is supposed to do, the meaning of your example input data, or what your intended outcome is. I recommend isolating the specific tasks you are trying to accomplish. Another tip would be to not query the DOM repeatedly for an element that doesn't change, query once, cache the result.

Comment: the Menu bar should look like this:

[Jeanette Angie Angela ........]

i set the Elements Jeanette and Jeanette to be not visible.

Comment: when i click on Go Forward i want to show 
[ Angie Angela ........]
when i click on Go Back:
[Jeanette Angela Angela .....]
then save this state to local storage

Comment: My purpose is to build an object network like wiki... and if you are reading about an object you can click for example on go forward to open the extension of it and show it on the menu bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the elements in Javascript and set the elements that you need to hidden, and on click you toggle the elements that you want, and then save to local storage:)